# Static compilation in linux using g++

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, g++

I compiled OpenSSL libraries statically. I want to compile `MyModule` with OpenSSL libraries statically. I am using a Makefile to do the same with

```
LDFLAGS      = $(LD_SHARED_FLAGS) -fPIC -static -lssl -lcrypto
```

`LD_SHARED_FLAGS` in root Makefile has

```
LD_SHARED_FLAGS     = -z text
```

When I run make, I get this,

```bash
g++ -shared -L../../lib  -z text -fPIC -static -lssl -lcrypto  -o libMyModule.so debug_utils.o  MyModule.o   labels.o -L/path_to_openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lc
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbeginT.o: error adding symbols: Bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [libMyModule.so] Error 1
```

Am I using the right flags for static compilation?

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I think you mean *link*, not *compile*.

Comment: Did you heed the error message's advice to "*recompile with `-fPIC`*"?

Answer (score 7):

It appears you want to link your static libraries `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` into your
shared library `libMyModule.so`.

Adding the GCC option [`-static`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) to your linkage command does not have just that effect,
but a much bigger one. It's effect is to request a *fully static linkage*. The linker must find and use
static versions of *all* required libraries: not just the ones you specify in your
linkage command but also the default ones: `libc`, `libstdc++`, `libgcc`, and also the static-linkage
variants of the C runtime support binaries, `crt*.o`.

Probably, you don't want all that `-static` stuff, and even if you don't mind having it,
it is incompatible with `-shared`.

You need `-shared`, of course, to make a shared library. All object files that are linked into
a shared library must be Position Independent Code, compiled with `-fPIC`.

The error you encounter:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbeginT.o: \
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; \
recompile with -fPIC
```

tells you that the C runtime binary `crtbeginT.o` required for your linkage wasn't compiled with `-fPIC`; isn't
position-indpendent code and therefore can't be linked into a shared library.

But `crtbeginT.o` is required for your linkage by the `-static` option. If you didn't
specify `-static`, then `crtbeginS.o` would be linked instead, which is the PIC variant of
this runtime binary, for linking with shared libraries, and the error would not occur.

So don't specify `-static`. It doesn't mix with `-shared` and it is not the way to link
static versions of `libssl` and `libcrypto` into `libMyModule.so`.

There is more than one way to achieve that. The simplest is to replace `-lssl -lcrypto`
in your linkage command with options that explictly specify the static versions of
just those libraries, i.e.

```
-l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a
```

Comment: Wow that was probably the best answer i've ever encountered. THX a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the openssl static libs with -fPIC.

Comment: I don't know what `R_X86_64_32` is, but it suggests you've built and are linking 32-bit binaries. If you do `file ...` on the openssl libs, does it say 32 or 64? (the X86_64 is the CPU arch, not the binary bitness).

Comment: file libcrypto.a
libcrypto.a: current ar archive